# Tried everything, but can not remove duplicate XML lines using xsl stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

As someone new to xsl, I have tried various examples from these posts, but for my particular XML file I cannot remove duplicate "TaskName" lines. I HAVE been successful eliminating multiple "ResourceName" entries, but only want a given task to appear once under the ResourceName.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. Here is my xml (sorry for the long file, but I think needed for clarity), my xsl, the output I am getting, and showing the output I'd like to get.

XML source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ResourceAssignments.xsl"?>
<ResourceAllocationReport>
   <DetailedData>
      <ResourceAllocation>
         <Group>Week Starting on 7/24/11</Group>
         <TaskResourceAllocation>
            <TaskName>DEV-23876 Task A</TaskName>
            <TaskDuration>5 days</TaskDuration>
            <ResourceName>John Smith</ResourceName>
            <AllocatedHours>2.400</AllocatedHours>
         </TaskResourceAllocation>
      </ResourceAllocation>
      <ResourceAllocation>
         <Group>Week Starting on 7/31/11</Group>
         <TaskResourceAllocation>
            <TaskName>DEV-23873 Task B</TaskName>
            <TaskDuration>2 days</TaskDuration>
            <ResourceName>John Smith</ResourceName>
            <AllocatedHours>4.000</AllocatedHours>
         </TaskResourceAllocation>
      </ResourceAllocation>
      <ResourceAllocation>
         <Group>Week Starting on 8/7/11</Group>
         <TaskResourceAllocation>
            <TaskName>DEV-23879 Task C</TaskName>
            <TaskDuration>10 days</TaskDuration>
            <ResourceName>John Smith</ResourceName>
            <AllocatedHours>1.600</AllocatedHours>
         </TaskResourceAllocation>
      </ResourceAllocation>
      <ResourceAllocation>
         <TaskResourceAllocation>
            <TaskName>DEV-22837  List edit</TaskName>
            <TaskDuration>10 days</TaskDuration>
            <ResourceName>Sam Adams</ResourceName>
            <AllocatedHours>5.000</AllocatedHours>
         </TaskResourceAllocation>
      </ResourceAllocation>
      <ResourceAllocation>
         <Group>Week Starting on 9/4/11</Group>
         <TaskResourceAllocation>
            <TaskName>DEV-19006  System Configuration Report</TaskName>
            <TaskDuration>12 days</TaskDuration>
            <ResourceName>Kimberly Clark</ResourceName>
            <AllocatedHours>7.000</AllocatedHours>
         </TaskResourceAllocation>
      </ResourceAllocation>
      <ResourceAllocation>
         <TaskResourceAllocation>
            <TaskName>DEV-19006  System Configuration Report</TaskName>
            <TaskDuration>12 days</TaskDuration>
            <ResourceName>Sam Adams</ResourceName>
            <AllocatedHours>7.000</AllocatedHours>
         </TaskResourceAllocation>
      </ResourceAllocation>
      <ResourceAllocation>
         <TaskResourceAllocation>
            <TaskName>DEV-22837  List edit</TaskName>
            <TaskDuration>10 days</TaskDuration>
            <ResourceName>Sam Adams</ResourceName>
            <AllocatedHours>8</AllocatedHours>
         </TaskResourceAllocation>
      </ResourceAllocation>
      <ResourceAllocation>
         <Group>Week Starting on 9/25/11</Group>
         <TaskResourceAllocation>
            <TaskName>DEV-15997  Change modifiers for components</TaskName>
            <TaskDuration>15 days</TaskDuration>
            <ResourceName>Kimberly Clark</ResourceName>
            <AllocatedHours>8.000</AllocatedHours>
         </TaskResourceAllocation>
      </ResourceAllocation>
      <ResourceAllocation>
         <Group>Week Starting on 10/2/11</Group>
         <TaskResourceAllocation>
            <TaskName>DEV-15997  Change modifiers for components</TaskName>
            <TaskDuration>15 days</TaskDuration>
            <ResourceName>Kimberly Clark</ResourceName>
            <AllocatedHours>2.000</AllocatedHours>
         </TaskResourceAllocation>
      </ResourceAllocation>
   </DetailedData>
</ResourceAllocationReport>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" /> 

  <xsl:key name="ResourceKey" match="TaskResourceAllocation" use="ResourceName" /> 

  <xsl:template match="ResourceAllocation"> 
    <body> 
      <xsl:apply-templates select="TaskResourceAllocation[generate-id(.) = 
                                   generate-id(key('ResourceKey',ResourceName)[1])]"/> 
    </body> 
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="TaskResourceAllocation"> 
     <h2><xsl:value-of select="ResourceName" /></h2> 
     <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('ResourceKey',ResourceName)"> 
          <xsl:if test="not(. = preceding::TaskName)">
             <tr> 
                <td> 
                   <xsl:value-of select="TaskName" /> 
                </td> 
                <td> 
                   <xsl:value-of select="TaskDuration" /> 
                </td> 
             </tr> 
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
     </table> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output (But I do NOT want duplicated tasks):

```
John Smith
DEV-23876 Task A 5 days 
DEV-23873 Task B 2 days 
DEV-23879 Task C 10 days 

Sam Adams
DEV-22837 List edit 10 days 
DEV-19006 System Configuration Report 12 days 
DEV-22837 List edit 10 days 

Kimberly Clark
DEV-19006 System Configuration Report 12 days 
DEV-15997 Change modifiers for components 15 days 
DEV-15997 Change modifiers for components 15 days
```

Desired output:

```
John Smith
DEV-23876 Task A 5 days 
DEV-23873 Task B 2 days 
DEV-23879 Task C 10 days 

Sam Adams
DEV-19006 System Configuration Report 12 days 
DEV-22837 List edit 10 days 

Kimberly Clark
DEV-19006 System Configuration Report 12 days 
DEV-15997 Change modifiers for components 15 days
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is sound enough - the problem seems to be that you are comparing ResourceName against TaskName, which will never match:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="key('ResourceKey',ResourceName)"> 
          <xsl:if test="not(. = preceding::TaskName)">
```

following up ... if you want to correct this (and stay w/xslt 1.0), try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="TaskName[not(preceding::TaskName=.)]">
  ... desired output here ...
</xsl:template>
```

run this template from some enclosing context using `<xsl:apply-templates /> or <xsl:apply-templates select=".//TaskName" />`

Comment: Hmm... yes, now that you mention it that doesn't seem correct. Yet the "if test" line doesn't seem to really have much effect on the output. And changing "TaskName" to "ResourceName" produces the same output. Guess I'm just unclear on what sort of conditional would work here.

Comment: Hey, thanks - indeed your follow-up solution eliminates all duplicates. My only remaining problem is where a particular task is assigned to multiple people. In that case, the task only appears under the first person in the list. Trying to fix that one, but no success yet. Still learning xsl. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Off top of my head you could do for-each-group something like this

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="key('ResourceKey',ResourceName)" group-by="TaskName"> 
     <tr>   
       <td>   
          <xsl:value-of select="TaskName" />   
       </td>   
       <td>   
          <xsl:value-of select="TaskDuration" />   
       </td>   
     </tr>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks Justin. So this would require XSLT 2.0 I presume. I may need to consider switching if this can't easily be done in 1.0